# When will android broadcasts intent ACTION_PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

About ACTION_PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION intent, the android docs says:

`Sent to the system package verifier when a package needs to be verified. The data contains the package URI.

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.`
Found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION

But what kind of verification does it means? In what kinds of occasions or scenarios will android broadcast this intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [recent source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java) (around line 10669), it appears that the system will broadcast this intent during the installation of a new package if there are any package verifier installed:

```
            /*
             * Determine if we have any installed package verifiers. If we
             * do, then we'll defer to them to verify the packages.
             */
```

As for an explanation of what package verifiers are and what they do, my understanding is that they will need to have the PACKAGE_VERIFICATION_AGENT permission (reserved for system apps) which gives them the ability to respond to the broadcast to [accept or reject the installation of the new package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#verifyPendingInstall(int,%20int)). The Google Play Store app is a verification agent that appears to use Google's online app verification service to perform this function.

Here is a page that has [a lot of interesting information](http://irq5.io/2014/12/01/android-internals-package-verifiers/) on the subject (along with several other pages that comes up if you do a "android package verifier" search online).